# Finding extended properties associated with a column with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The query below selects columns in a given table which have a specific extended property set.

I then wish to use a `LEFT JOIN` to find all additional extended properties associated with the column, with a view to `PIVOT` this out at a future step.

I am looking for a way to limit the highlighted join to only properties associated with the current column and have highlighted the problem area below.

```
SELECT
    C.NAME AS ColumnName
    ,PropertyName = CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), EXP2.NAME)
    ,PropertyValue = CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), EXP2.value)
FROM sys.extended_properties AS EXP

LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS C ON C.object_id = EXP.major_id
    AND C.column_id = EXP.minor_id

-------------------------------------------------------
-- I'm looking for all 'additional' extended properties 
-- associated with this column, however the following 
-- join only joins back to table level
-------------------------------------------------------

LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties AS EXP2 ON OBJECT_NAME(EXP2.major_id) = OBJECT_NAME(EXP.major_id)
    AND NOT EXP2.NAME = 'DEFINE_IMPORTABLE'
    AND EXP2.NAME LIKE 'DEFINE_%'

--- ^ Perhaps joining to another alias of sys.columns would work here?

WHERE EXP.class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
    AND EXP.NAME = 'DEFINE_IMPORTABLE'
    AND EXP.value = '1'
    AND NOT C.NAME IS NULL
    AND OBJECT_NAME(EXP.major_id) = 'MyTable'
```

Comment: You're almost there, just renove OBJECT_NAME(EXP2.major_id) = OBJECT_NAME(EXP.major_id)   (this would word but comparing ids is cheaper)
add EXP2.major_id = C.object_id AND EXP2.minor_id = C.column_id

Comment: Thanks @MWillemse - that was spot on.